# How to humble yourself like a little child?

Tags: greek, matthew, jesus

Matthew 18:4

Whosoever therefore shall humble himself as this little child, the same is greatest in the kingdom of heaven.

Children are not particularly humble. What does Jesus mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

Jesus leaves his words in this instance open to interpretation, and does not clarify as to their precise meaning; however, the lesson was a practical one to his disciples that should not be too difficult to grasp.

Jesus does not mean that one should have a child's humility, but rather that one should be humble enough to become like a child.  For an adult to seek to emulate the wisdom or ways of a child would certainly be humbling.

And what are the positives of children?  They are forgiving, trusting, and learn quickly when taught.  These are characteristics that Heaven appreciates in every follower of Christ.

**From the Lord's Prayer**

> And forgive us our debts, **as we forgive** our debtors. (Matthew 6:12,
> KJV)

**From Christ's Other Teachings**

> Take my yoke upon you, and **learn of me;** for I am meek and lowly in
> heart: and ye shall find rest unto your souls. (Matthew 11:29, KJV)
>
> And **in his name** shall the Gentiles **trust.** (Matthew 12:21, KJV)

To become like a child in traits of character such as these is what Christ was teaching.  His teachings in other passages would agree.  In the Lord's prayer, Christ teaches that we must forgive to be forgiven.  He teaches that we should learn of him, and trust him.  These are all common attributes observed in children.

Answer (score 1):

The first or literal meaning of ταπεινόω is to *lower* or *level*.  Thus,  ὅστις ταπεινώσει ἑαυτὸν ὡς τὸ παιδίον τοῦτο (NA28) means "whoever will lower himself to the level of this child."  That is the meaning of humble here; not the attitude of the child, but the rank of the child.

> ταπεινόω fut. ταπεινώσω; 1 aor. ἐταπείνωσα. Pass.: pf. ptc. τεταπεινωμένος; 1 aor. ἐταπεινώθην; 1 fut ταπεινωθήσομαι (Hippocr.+; LXX; En. 106, 1; Ep. Arist. 257; Philo, Joseph.) *lower, make low*. 1. lit. (cf. Diod. S. 1, 36, 8; Bar 5:7; En. 1, 6) ὄρος, βουνόν *level* a mountain, hill Lk 3:5 (Is 40:4). 2. fig.—a. *humble, humiliate* by assigning to a low(er) place or exposing to shame, w. acc. of the pers. or thing treated in this manner ... b. humble, make humble in a good sense ...  c. In accordance w. OT usage, ταπεινοῦν τὴν ἑαυτοῦ ψυχήν (Lev 16:29, 31; 23:27; Ps 34:13; Is 58:3 al.) or ταπεινοῦσθαι (Sir 34:26; 2 Esdr [Ezra] 8:21. Cf. the prayers for vengeance fr. Rheneia [Dssm., LO 353f, LAE 413ff=Dit., Syll.3 1181, 11] θεὸς ᾧ πᾶσα ψυχὴ ταπεινοῦται. Cf. Dssm., LO 357f, LAE 419) means *discipline oneself, fast*
> --
> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 804-805). Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

**Commentaries**

> It is not that the child humbled himself, but that the child is humble from the nature of the case in relation to older persons. That is true, however “bumptious” the child himself may be. Bruce observes that to humble oneself is “the most difficult thing in the world for saint as for sinner.”
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Mt 18:4). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

> *whoever humbles himself*: Mt. adds the precept of lowering oneself to clarify what is meant by becoming like a child. In ancient law the child was not a person in the full legal sense. He was not only under the authority of the parents, he was their property; he had no power of self-assertion and no power of independent action. This “denial of self” (16:24) is the proper posture of those who would be “great”—that is, the bearers of authority—in the reign.5. The saying is joined to the preceding by the catchword “child.” “Child” here is possibly not meant in its literal sense, although the same idea is stated in 19:10-13; the word may designate the simple who become disciples and who already have that simplicity that Jesus states as the condition of membership. With these “little ones” Jesus identifies himself. Elsewhere those who receive the disciples receive Jesus (10:40).
> --
> Brown, R. E., Fitzmyer, J. A., & Murphy, R. E. (1996). The Jerome Biblical commentary (Vol. 2, p. 94). Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 18:4

> Whosoever therefore shall humble himself as this little child, the same is greatest in the kingdom of heaven.

humbles
ταπεινώσει (tapeinōsei)
Verb - Future Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 5013: To make or **bring low**, humble, humiliate; pass: To be humbled. From tapeinos; to depress; figuratively, to humiliate.

```
Whosoever therefore       shall humble      himself as this little child, 
the same                  is greatest       in the kingdom of heaven.
```

Jesus meant it as a contrast. If one lowers himself like a little child in this world, he is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven.

NIV:

> Therefore, whoever takes the lowly position of this child is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven.

Matthew 23:

> 12
> For those who exalt themselves will be humbled, and those who humble themselves will be exalted.

Answer (score 0):

The disciples came to Jesus and said, “Who then is greatest in the kingdom of heaven?” (Mt 18:1). In answer, Jesus places a child among his disciples to counter the ideas of rank and ambition that underlie their question. These concepts represent the spirit of the world that are antithetical to the spirit of faith. In the gospel of Luke, Jesus notes how people seek out “the places of honor” and tells a parable to discourage this behavior.

> Now He began telling a parable to the invited guests when He noticed
> how they had been picking out the places of honor at the table, saying
> to them, 8 “Whenever you are invited by someone to a wedding feast, do
> not take the place of honor, for someone more distinguished than you
> may have been invited by him, 9 and the one who invited you both will
> come and say to you, ‘Give your place to this person,’ and then in
> disgrace you will proceed to occupy the last place. 10 But whenever
> you are invited, go and take the last place, so that when the one who
> has invited you comes, he will say to you, ‘Friend, move up higher’;
> then you will have honor in the sight of all who are dining at the
> table with you. 11 For everyone who exalts himself will be humbled,
> and the one who humbles himself will be exalted.” – Lk 20:7-11

The pride that children have in their small accomplishments is untainted by the desire to best or dominate others and thus does not contradict the humble spirit that Jesus teaches. Children are also powerless and completely dependent on their parents. They thus serve as the perfect model of what it means to be a humble child of God for whom greatness is defined not by achievement and self-reliance, but by God’s grace and protection.

> “See that you do not look down on one of these little ones; for I say
> to you that their angels in heaven continually see the face of My
> Father who is in heaven. – Mt 18:10
>
> Now we have not received the
> spirit of the world, but the Spirit who is from God, so that we may
> know the things freely given to us by God. – 1 Cor 2:12